# Simple Filter Python script for Text

Tags: python, regex, search, filter

I am trying to create what must be a simple filter function which runs a regex against a text file and returns all words containing that particular regex.

so for example if i wanted to find all words that contained "abc", and I had the list: `abcde`, `bce`, `xyz` and `zyxabc` the script would return `abcde` and `zyxabc`.

I have a script below however I am not sure if it is just the regex I am failing at or not. it just returns abc twice rather than the full word. thanks.

```
import re

text = open("test.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile(r'(abc)')

for line in text:
    target = regex.findall(line)
    for word in target:
        print word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you dont need regex for such task you can simply `split` your lines to create a list of words then loop over your words list and use `in` operator :

```
 with open("test.txt") as f :
     for line in f:
         for w in line.split():
              if 'abc' in w :
                   print w
```

Answer (score 2):

Your methodology is correct however, you can change your Regex to `r'.*abc.*'`, in the sense

```
 regex = re.compile(r'.*abc.*')
```

This will match all the lines with `abc` in them`The wildcards`.*` will match all your letters in the line.

A small Demo with that particular line changed would print

```
abcde
zyxabc
```

Note, As Kasra [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265362/4099593) it is better to use `in` operator in such cases